# Сравнительный оборот с союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая: "**Он, как подопытный кролик Дмитрия, не мог ему отказать**"?

Дмитрий ученый, а "он" — человек, который решил помочь ученому. Здесь оборот с союзом "как" сравнительный или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После редактирования:

**Он как подопытный кролик Дмитрия,  отказать ему (он) не мог.**

***Как подопытный кролик*** относится к именной части сказуемого, запятой нет.

Предложение бессоюзное, в его составе второе предложение (с пропущенным местоимением *он*) распространяет первое.

**Примечание.**

Он, как подопытный кролик Дмитрия, не мог ему отказать. Этот вариант двусмысленный,  его можно принять за тождество (а не сравнение)  со значением причины: Он, будучи подопытным кроликом...

Comment: Получается, это уже зависит от того, что хочет передать автор? И можно еще Вам один вопрос?

Comment: Зависит, конечно.  Я предполагала, что  здесь выражено недовольство тем, что он никогда не отказывает Дмитрию.  Мне вопрос тоже можно, если по близкой теме, а можно и всему обществу.

Comment: Здесь было уточнение причины, почему он не мог отказать. Меня мучают два предложения: 1) Он сидел в этой комнате как подопытный кролик. 2) Ель была украшена как новогодняя елка. В первом предложении запятой скорее всего не будет, ибо можно сказать " в качестве", а вот насчет второго...я сомневаюсь.

Comment: При решении этих задач важно учитывать структуру предложения. Оборот с союзом КАК обособляется часто, при этом он не входит в структуру основного предложения, но иногда оборот нельзя обособить, так как он  является частью сказуемого или  обстоятельством в основном сообщении,  тесно связанным со сказуемым.  Но достаточно распространить предложение (или изменить позицию оборота), и уже требуется  его обособление.

Comment: Сравните: Он сидел в этой комнате как подопытный кролик. - Он постоянно сидел у него в комнате, как подопытный кролик. Ель была украшена как новогодняя елка. - Ель была украшена  шариками и мишурой, как новогодняя елка. Я  распространила предложение, и оборот перестал быть обязательным, он уже не входит в основное предложение, а является попутным сравнением.

Comment: А если будет такое предложение: Он сидел как подопытный кролик у него в комнате? Запятых, как я понимаю, не будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78263/discussion-between--and-jasmin).

Comment: Неестественное предложение, неясно, что мы хотим сказать.  Где тема - рема, то есть предмет и сообщение о предмете?  Должно быть так:  Он сидел  у него в комнате //как подопытный кролик. А у Вас: Он сидел как подопытный кролик //у него в комнате? Мысль неясная.

Comment: Хорошо, только позже. Сформулируйте пока свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится, если в предложении есть обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом, который начинается с союза КАК, например: Ее голос звенел, как самый маленький колокольчик; Внизу, как зеркало, блестела вода;

Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК, если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия, например: Тропинка извивалась как змея. В таких случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ). Но не всегда обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной уверенностью отличить от обстоятельств сравнения.

То есть нужно отличать обстоятельства сравнения и обстоятельства образа действия и, соответственно, выделять обороты с КАК или нет.

Ель была украшена, как новогодняя елка. Это обстоятельство сравнения: Ель была украшена (так), как (бывает украшена) новогодняя елка. Нельзя сказать: Ель была украшена новогодней елкой, то есть оборот заменить существительным в творительном падеже.

Она держится как хозяйка; Здесь нельзя поставить запятую, так как *Она держится* без *как хозяйка* не имеет законченного смысла, в отличие от *Ель была украшена*.

"Некоторые случаи допускают двоякую пунктуацию в зависимости от оттенков значения, связанных с контекстом; ср.: Рецензируемую книгу можно рекомендовать как пособие для студентов ("в качестве пособия"). - Следует признать, что, как пособие для студентов, рецензируемая книга имеет ряд существенных недостатков ("будучи пособием" - с причинным оттенком значения)" 6 .

"Некоторые предложения допускают двоякую пунктуацию в зависимости от их истолкования; ср.: Я относился к нему как к брату ("он мне брат"). - Я относился к нему, как к брату ("по-братски, хотя он мне не брат"); Он работал как батрак ("в качестве батрака", "батраком"). - Он работал, как батрак ("много", "подобно батраку")"

Comment: Тропинка   извивалась, как змея,  вдоль ручья, а потом свернула к опушке леса. Извивалась змеёй, можно заменить сущ. в Т.п. Не надо обособлять?

Comment: Обособление может зависеть от контекста, для примера сравним два варианта. (1) Праздник отмечали в саду. На кустах  развесили электрические фонарики, а ель была украшена как новогодняя Ёлка, то есть шариками и мишурой.  (2) Ночью выпал снег, и теперь ель была укрАшена, как  новогодняя Ёлка:  её белый наряд сверкал на солнце золотистыми огоньками. Таким образом, формальные признаки помогают нам решить задачу, но не определяют окончательный ответ.

Comment: Я относился к нему как к брату.  Он работал как батрак. Обособление невозможно,  оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан  со сказуемым.  Не все варианты допускают двойное толкование.

Comment: Ответ полезный, но есть в нем спорные примеры. Если человек работал батраком, не говорят, по-моему, "он работал как батрак", однако я бы и при сравнении запятую не ставил (он работал как батрак = он работал тяжело). *Бѣдный Глинка работаетъ какъ батракъ, а проку все нѣтъ. [А. С. Пушкин. Письмо П. А. Плетневу (1831.01.07)]*